# Extension doesn´t work after deleted Cache

Tags: caching, typo3, fluid

i have a problem with one of my extensions i created with Extensionbuilder. 
After i deleted the Cache there is no content anymore!

```
<f:flashMessages renderMode="div"/>

<div class="tx-camping-list">
    <f:for each="{offers}" as="offer" iteration="it">

        <div class="content-list-item">
            <div class="contentLeft floatLeft">
                <f:render partial="BaseItem/ListImages" arguments="{item:offer}" />
                <div class="wrap-right floatRight">
                    <h3>
                        <f:link.action arguments="{offer:offer}">
                            <f:format.raw>{offer.names}</f:format.raw>
                        </f:link.action>
                    </h3>
                    <h4>
                        <f:format.raw>{offer.teaser}</f:format.raw>
                    </h4>
                    <div class="description"><f:format.crop maxCharacters="240"><f:format.html>{offer.description}</f:format.html></f:format.crop>
                    <p>
                        <f:link.action arguments="{offer:offer}">
                            <f:translate key="read_more" default="Read more" /> &gt;
                        </f:link.action>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="roomPrice floatRight">
                <f:render partial="Price/ListPriceBox" arguments="{item:offer}" />
                <f:render partial="BaseItem/Button" arguments="{item:offer,type:'Offer'}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="clearFloat"></div>
        </div>
    </f:for>
</div>
```

The image, {offer.names}, {offer.teaser} etc. is NULL, BUT the link {offer:offer} is working

When i reload the page the first time after i deleted the Cache i get the error: 
***The argument “each” was registered with type “array”, but is of type “string” in view helper***

After a reload everything works fine except this plugin!

Maybe some of you can help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `<f:debug>` to find out what you real values are. You cannot loop over a string. Most likely, you are mistaken over your nesting level of your object.

Also do not use `<f:format.raw>` unless you already ensured, that the contend is htmlspecialchar'd. Otherwise you loose the XSS protection.

Answer (score 0):

**This can just fix the error if its caused by a missing reference on records**

You could try to add the following line of code to your **setup.ts** (or .txt; depending on configuration and personal preferences):

File: *slider/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts:*

```
plugin.tx_slider.persistence.storagePid = 15
```

**Note: replace tx_slider with your extensionkey and the 15 with the pagenumber where your records (in this case your offer-records) are located**